# Last non Null in a Pivot SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have the following table w/ data in it:
[image]

I have the following sql query to manipulate the data, grouping all data w/ same unix_timestamp for use of a graphing api (timeline):

```
select * from 
                (
                    select unix_timestamp, date_time, input_raw, tag_id 
                    from [200030].[dbo].inputs
                    WHERE inputs.date_time > dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
                    AND
                    (tag_id = 92084 OR tag_id = 92106 OR tag_id = 92127 OR tag_id = 92149 OR tag_id = 92164 OR tag_id = 92193 OR tag_id = 92215)
                ) src
                pivot
                (
                    max(input_raw)
                    for tag_id in ([92084], [92106], [92127], [92149], [92164], [92193], [92215])
                ) piv
                ORDER by unix_timestamp DESC
```

And it's giving me these results (the numbered column names are from the tag_id field of the original table:

[image]

This is great accept I need one more thing out of the query though.  I need the entry under the numbered columns to be the last non-Null value.  Unless there is no previous non-Nulls that is.  For instance, lines 4-8 under the column 92149, would need to be 294 instead of Null.

And advice?

Thanks

Comment: Please supply some example data and desired results.

Comment: Are the columns always going to be hardcoded or are you planning on making them dynamic?

Comment: php is building the query based on user selection of tag_ids.  Just the tag_id parts

Comment: the sample data would be hard to give you.  I am pulling from thousands of tag_ids.  I can give you the structure of the table though.

Comment: I have a recursive CTE that can do it at the column level, but I think the most efficient way would be to simply use a cursor and start at the bottom and work your way back.

Comment: @Mildfire - It doesn't have to be real data. A cut down example with (say) 6 rows and 6 columns would do. I have no idea what you mean by *I need the entry under the numbered columns to be the last non-Null value. Unless there is no previous non-Nulls that is.*

Comment: I've been trying to get a recursive function in php to work.  Going through the returned array of results to find the last non null but thought maybe there was an sql solution.

Comment: Ah I see what you need. A recursive CTE *could* do it (I would materialise the intermediate results into a `#temp` table first) but probably easier in the application. You just need to loop through row by row and remember the values you wrote for each column on the previous row.

Comment: What database and what version are you using?

Comment: @Mildfire . .. 'Tis a shame.  Oracle 11g has a function that does exactly this and SQL Server 2012 has something that could be forced.  SQL Server 2008 requires a more brute force approach.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is essentially that you have "missing" data on timestamps because only one tag comes in at a time.  One approach is to fill in the missing data.

This query gets all combinations of timestamp and tag and then gets the most recent input_raw value *before* the pivote.  The query uses a correlated subquery for this.

```
                select unix_timestamp, date_time, tag_id,
                       coalesce(input_raw,
                                (select top 1 input_raw
                                 from inputs i
                                 where i.tag_id = tags.tag_id and
                                       i.unix_timestamp < tags.unix_timestamp
                                 order by unix_timestamp
                                )
                               ) as input_raw
                from (select 92084 as tag_id union all
                      select 92106 union all select 92127 union all select 92149 union all
                      select 92164 union all select 92193 union all select 92215
                     ) tags cross join
                     (select distinct unix_timestamp, datetime, input_raw
                      from [200030].[dbo].inputs
                      WHERE inputs.date_time > dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
                     ) t left outer join
                     [200030].[dbo].inputs i
                     on i.tag_id = tags.tag_id and
                        i.unix_timestamp = tags.unix_timestamp and
                        i.datetime = tags.datetime
                WHERE inputs.date_time > dateadd(day,-1,getdate())
```

This replaces your inner subquery.